# call dispose on every graphics object or just 'Graphics' object?

Tags: asp.net

Do I need to also do:

```
bitmap.dispose();
Brush.dispose();
brush2.dispose();
```

Or will it be sufficient to just do:

```
graphics.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short; you should call `Dispose` on all instances that you create of types that implement `IDisposable`. So, if you create a `Graphics` object, and a `Brush` to draw on it, both should be diposed.

One example of what *not* to dispose, is the graphics object that is passed into `OnPaint` methods. This instance is created by the framework, and may be passed to several other method calls. Also the brushes found in [`Brushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes.aspx) and [`SystemBrushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systembrushes.aspx) and the pens found in  [`Pens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pens.aspx) and [`SystemPens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systempens.aspx) are shared and should (and could) not be disposed by your code.

Comment: so i should not dispose the brushes? or pens?

Comment: You should dispose brushes and pens *if you create them yourself*. The brushes and pens that you get from `SystemBrushes` and `SystemPens` are not created by you, you "borrow" them from the framework. But if you create a brush (`Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(...);`), then you should also dispose it.

Comment: what if i creat them as such : graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.Black))?

Comment: @zsharp: in short: don't. Wrap it all up in a using block instead: `using(Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)) { graphics.FillPath(b); }`